# How to search in select box options and delete duplicated options using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, form-helpers

I have such task: when user edits his object - first option in the list will be the value of object.

I'm generating my select list using this code:

```
    <%= f.select :category, options_for_select([
      "#{@website.category}",
      "Banking",
      "Computers",
      "Coupons",
      "Directory",
      "Fashion",
      "Finance",
      "Gifts",
      "Maps",
      "Media",
      "Mobile",
      "News",
      "Tickets",
      "Tech blog",
      "Tech website",
      "Trains",
      "Travel",
      "Transportation - general",
       "Recipes",
      "Another... "])%>
```

Can anyone suggest how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here the doc about [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

You can set a default value (or selected value) of the select-box as the second argument.
In your case it would be like :

```
<%= f.select :category, options_for_select([
  "Banking",
  "Computers",
  "Coupons",
  "Directory",
  "Fashion",
  "Finance",
  "Gifts",
  "Maps",
  "Media",
  "Mobile",
  "News",
  "Tickets",
  "Tech blog",
  "Tech website",
  "Trains",
  "Travel",
  "Transportation - general",
   "Recipes",
  "Another... "], @website.category)%>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, but it will duplicate category from the list

Comment: No. Read the doc. The value that `@website.category` returns must be the same value as the option.

Comment: Sorry, I'm angry a little bit. I have big troubles for newbie)

Comment: I wish you have better day than me

Comment: one more thing - how can I validate Select box using jQuery validation plugin ?